# Dynamic PDF generation using QuickPDFLibrary

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, pdf-generation

I am trying to generate a dynamic PDF using .NET. The library I have find is QuickPDFLibrary. I know there are several other libraries that can do this such as iTextSharp; however, they require licenses for commercial applications. QuickPDFLibrary states that they support ASP.NET; however, I can't seem to get it to work and cannot find a tutorial on their site that documents using it with ASP.NET. I followed the procedures to set up the DLL and ActiveX but was unable to get either of them to work in the context of an aspx page. My code is as follows.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public QuickPDFAX0816.PDFLibrary qp;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        qp = new QuickPDFAX0816.PDFLibrary(); 
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        qp.UnlockKey("UNLOCK KEY HERE");

        // This function draws text onto a document

        // Setup the parameters
        string fileName = "drawText.pdf";

        // Check to see if the library has been successfully unlocked
        if (qp.Unlocked() == 1)
        {
            // Set origin co-ordinates to top left of page
            qp.SetOrigin(1);

            // Call the DrawText function
            qp.DrawText(100, 100, "Hello world from C# and the ActiveX edition of Quick PDF Library");

            // Save the changes to the document on the local disk (in the debug folder)
            int result = qp.SaveToFile(fileName);

            if (result == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("IT worked!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("IT failed!");
            }
            // Open PDF automatically
            //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fileName);

        }
        else
        {
            // If library could not be unlocked warn the user
            Console.WriteLine("License key could not be validated. The library was not unlocked.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the recommendations. I decided to go with ABCpdf.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Try PDFSharp http://www.pdfsharp.net/. It's open source with MIT license so it's very friendly license for commercial products, totally .Net (no ActiveX), and they have good samples http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/PDFsharpSamples.ashx to get you started